# Eclipse Cursor Position Stays at Line Beginning

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, google-java-format

I'm wondering if the following behavior of the Eclipse formatter is a bug or not, and if so, if there is any workaround.

After I click `return` and create a new line, I can see Eclipse has automatically inserted some spaces on the new line, according to the indentation formatting settings. However the cursor remains at position 1. I **cannot** move the cursor to the end of the line using arrow keys. If I start typing it automatically jumps to the end of the line.

Before creating new line:
[image: before creating new line]

After (see cursor at position 1 of line 244):
[image: shows misplaced cursor at beginning of line]

I can reproduce this using the Eclipse formatter profile [from here](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml) but I think can be reproduced whenever you have `tab policy` set to `spaces only`.

Using Eclipse for Mac version

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200
```

Comment: I usually don't have problems like this, but then again, I don't mess with eclipse settings. Have you tried changing your tab policy?

Comment: I don't get this problem and I have spaces only. Same Eclipse release and platform.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart AFAIK changing the Tab Policy to tabs or mixed does indeed "fix" the problem (not a solution for my team though since we are set on spaces)

Comment: Just ignore it then. If the cursor moves to the correct position when you start typing then ignore it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to disable the "Smart caret positioning at line start and end" on the Text Editors preference page.

Comment: @nitind Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to affect his particular behavior. However that led to me to see the setting `Enter key adjusts the indentation on the new line` -- and I now think this behavior is a bug related to that particular setting.

Comment: @DaveL. where is that setting? same problem here..